# Mochiweb debug (like ejabberd debug)

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mochiweb

I was wonderng if anyone knows of a way to get into Mochiweb like ejabberd does when you run /sbin/ejabberdctl debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure that `-sname $NODE@$HOST` (or `-name $NODE@$FULLHOST`) is present in parameters of `erl` call in `start.sh` of your mochiweb-based project
2. Create file `debug.sh` with the following code:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   erl -sname debug_$NODE@$HOST -remsh $NODE@$HOST
   ```

Make sure not to mix `sname` and `name` in scripts, because [nodes with short names can not communicate with nodes with full names (and vice versa)](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id2277180). Additionally make sure to use [the same cookie on both nodes](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html#id2277412) either via `-setcookie` parameter of `erl` or via `~/.erlang.cookie` file.

Of course you have to replace $NODE, $HOST and $FULLHOST with appropriate values.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  It didn't work at first b/c I had to also -setcookie to match, but it worked after that.  Thanks a lot

Comment: Good point about the cookie. I'm using cookie from `~/.erlang.cookie` file so forgot about `-setcookie` thing :)